# Outlook and Word randomly hang

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, freeze

It boggles my mind. I've reinstalled the whole system several times put the problem keeps coming back. Office 2016 apps, including Word and Outlook, randomly become un-responding. Sometimes Word fails to open and it just sits at the splash screen with the progress dots keep moving. I tried repairing office from the control panel.

I tried running this command in powershell:
`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

and

`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` in CMD. The problem came back. This is a very difficult problem to troubleshoot as it doesn't happen every time.

I just want to confirm I am getting updates for Microsoft Office. Is there a way to do that? Under Windows update > advanced options I have checked "Give me updates for other microsoft products when I update Windows". Is this correct?

I installed a good Antivirus and no viruses detected. Also sometimes the computer fails at shuting down.

Comment: Have you checked your hard disks for smart errors?

Comment: Just did. No errors. It's an SSD.

Comment: @DavidPostill I finally isolated the cause of the hanging. Whenever Windows Updates starts installing updates in the background, Microsoft Office apps become extremely unstable until the updates have finished and the computer has rebooted.

Comment: Hmm.  I suggest you self answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It has been my observation that whenever the system became unstable, in particular Microsoft Office apps, Windows Updates was running in the background and had automatically started installing updates. The instability continues until all updates have finished installing and the computer restarted. My advice for others with this problem is to allow Windows Updates to finish installing up dates and to leave the computer alone until it is finished.

TL;DR Windows Updates causes system instability.